# Referencing a BASH variable in C code

Tags: c, bash

I want to go to the HOME directory using C code. How do I access $HOME from the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have double quotes. `getenv("HOME");`

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
getenv("HOME")
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not just a bash variable, it's an environment variable. Have a look at [`getenv`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

...

// The value will be NULL if the variable doesn't exist
char* home = getenv("HOME");
```

Answer (score 3):

try [`getenv("HOME");`](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Environment-Access.html#Environment-Access)

Comment: You definitely want double quotes.

Comment: Thanks. fixed. Been a long while since I did any C coding. Been stuck in PHP purgatory for far too long.